# Slope of a line using houghline transformation c# Aforge.Net

Tags: c#, aforge, hough-transform

I used the code from aforge.net library

```
 HoughLineTransformation lineTransform = new HoughLineTransformation( );
  // apply Hough line transofrm
  lineTransform.ProcessImage( sourceImage );
 Bitmap houghLineImage = lineTransform.ToBitmap( );
 // get lines using relative intensity
 HoughLine[] lines = lineTransform.GetLinesByRelativeIntensity( 0.5 );

foreach ( HoughLine line in lines )
 {
  // get line's radius and theta values
  int    r = line.Radius;
double t = line.Theta;

// check if line is in lower part of the image
if ( r < 0 )
{
    t += 180;
    r = -r;
}

// convert degrees to radians
t = ( t / 180 ) * Math.PI;
 Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",t,r)

// get image centers (all coordinate are measured relative
// to center)
int w2 = image.Width /2;
int h2 = image.Height / 2;

double x0 = 0, x1 = 0, y0 = 0, y1 = 0;

if ( line.Theta != 0 )
{
    // none-vertical line
    x0 = -w2; // most left point
    x1 = w2;  // most right point

    // calculate corresponding y values
    y0 = ( -Math.Cos( t ) * x0 + r ) / Math.Sin( t );
    y1 = ( -Math.Cos( t ) * x1 + r ) / Math.Sin( t );
}
else
{
    // vertical line
    x0 = line.Radius;
    x1 = line.Radius;

    y0 = h2;
    y1 = -h2;
}

// draw line on the image
Drawing.Line( sourceData,
    new IntPoint( (int) x0 + w2, h2 - (int) y0 ),
    new IntPoint( (int) x1 + w2, h2 - (int) y1 ),
    Color.Red );
```

}

I added Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",t,r)  for the code to display slope and radius of lines.

In the output, the value of slope is either 45 or 135 degrees for all the lines in the image, though the image has different line slopes.
  What could be the reason?    Please help...

There are no compilation errors in the code.

Comment: do the lines you draw in the end based in the detected line parameterization look right?

Comment: What do you expect, what do you get? Without that, all we can say is that it works as written...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forget to apply a edge detection Filter, like Sobel. The Hough Line of Aforge uses every not black pixel to calculate a Line. If you have a large colored area, you will have many Lines with 45 and 135 slope degree.

Hope I understood what your question was.